# Implementing a PriorityQueue assistance

Tags: java, priority-queue

Typical student here, seeking some input for the final steps of an assignment.  Any help or tips to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Part of our assignment is to implement an Emergency Room PriorityQueue.  The details of the part I'm stuck on is as follows:

> Write a class called PatientQueue with:
>
> a. A default, no-arg
>   constructor
>
> b. Two public methods:
>   i. public void registerPatient(Patient p)
>   ii. public Patient getNextPatient()
>
> c. Internal use of a PriorityQueue and PatientComparator

Here's what I have so far:

In Patient.java:

```
package blah;

import java.util.Date;

public class Patient {

// data fields
protected String name;
protected int category;
protected Date timeArrived;

// accessors and mutators
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String nameIn) {
    this.name = nameIn;
}
public int getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public void setCategory(int categoryIn) {
    this.category = categoryIn;
}

public java.util.Date getTimeArrived() {
    return timeArrived;
}

// default constructor
public Patient() {
    this.name = "Default Name";
    this.category = 5; // unclassified Patients go to the end of the queue
    this.timeArrived = new Date();
}

// overloaded constructor
public Patient(String nameIn, int categoryIn) {
    this.name = nameIn;
    this.category = categoryIn;
    this.timeArrived = new Date();
}

} // end Patient class
```

In PatientComparator.java:

```
package blah;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class PatientComparator implements Comparator<Patient> {

public int compare(Patient p1, Patient p2) {
    if (p1.getCategory() < p2.getCategory())
        return -1;
    if (p1.getCategory() > p2.getCategory())
        return 1;
    else { if (p1.getTimeArrived().before(p2.getTimeArrived()))
        return -1;
           if (p1.getTimeArrived().after(p2.getTimeArrived()))
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

} // end PatientComparator class
```

In PatientQueue.java:

```
package blah;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class PatientQueue extends PriorityQueue<Patient> {

// default constructor
public PatientQueue() {

}

public void registerPatient(Patient p) {
            //NEED HELP IN THIS PART//
} // end registerPatient method

public Patient getNextPatient() {
    return (Patient)this.poll();
} // end getNextPatient method

} // end PatientQueue class
```

And, finally, in the driver EmergencyRoomSimulator.java:
    package blah;

```
import java.util.Random; 

public class EmergencyRoomSimulator { 

private static final int WAIT_LIMIT = 3000; // 1000 = 1 second 

private PatientQueue pq = new PatientQueue(); 

private void t() { 
    try {  Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(WAIT_LIMIT));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } 
} // end t method

private void patientArrives(Patient p) { 
    pq.registerPatient(p); 
    System.out.println(" ARRIVAL: " + p.getName()); 
    System.out.println(" time arrived: " + p.getTimeArrived()); 
    System.out.println(" category: " + p.getCategory()); 
    System.out.println("------------------------------------"); 
    t(); 
} // end patientArrives method

private void doctorVisits() { 
    Patient p = pq.getNextPatient(); 
    System.out.println(" VISIT: " + p.getName()); 
    System.out.println(" time arrived: " + p.getTimeArrived()); 
    System.out.println(" category: " + p.getCategory()); 
    System.out.println("------------------------------------"); 
    t(); 
} // end doctorVisits method

private void simulate() { 
    System.out.println("------------------------------------"); 
    System.out.println("ER OPEN"); 
    System.out.println("------------------------------------"); 
    patientArrives(new Patient("John Paul Jones", 3)); 
    patientArrives(new Patient("Thomas Paine", 1)); 
    patientArrives(new Patient("Joseph Brant", 2)); 
    doctorVisits(); 
    patientArrives(new Patient("Ethan Allen", 2)); 
    patientArrives(new Patient("Henry Knox", 4)); 
    patientArrives(new Patient("Patrick Henry", 2)); 
    doctorVisits(); 
    doctorVisits(); 
    patientArrives(new Patient("Mary Draper", 1)); 
    patientArrives(new Patient("Samuel Adams", 3)); 
    doctorVisits(); 
    doctorVisits(); 
    doctorVisits(); 
    doctorVisits(); 
    doctorVisits(); 
    System.out.println("------------------------------------"); 
    System.out.println("ER CLOSED"); 
    System.out.println("------------------------------------"); 
} // end simulate method

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    EmergencyRoomSimulator er = new EmergencyRoomSimulator(); 
    er.simulate(); 
} // end main 

} // end class
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

on the first `doctorVisits()` call in the main.  I know I'm missing the proper way to actually add and/or remove an object to/from the list, but I can't see what needs to happen in the `PatientQueue` class to actually trigger the `PriorityQueue` being used to add or "get" the next Patient.

Again, any advice is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: why not use `pq.add(p)` in your registerPatient method?

Comment: "pq" wouldn't be recognized(resolved) in that method if I simply added that line in. I agree in theory that's closer to what needs to happen, but I'm still disconnecting on how pq (in the main) relates to registerPatient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not even make a separate Comparator. You can just implement Comparable interface on your Patient class and implement the necessary compareTo method.
A quick implementation:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Patient p = (Patient) o;
    if (this.getCategory() < p.getCategory())
        return -1;
    if (this.getCategory() > p.getCategory())
        return 1;
    else { if (this.getTimeArrived().before(p.getTimeArrived()))
        return -1;
        if (this.getTimeArrived().after(p.getTimeArrived()))
           return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also add  `this.add(p)` in your registerPatient method.

Nothing else needed to get the program to work. More info on Comparable interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

---

EDIT //

After your comment I looked at the assignment more carefully and actually it says:

> c. Internal use of a PriorityQueue and PatientComparator

This means (at least how I would read it) that you don't actually have to extend the PriorityQueue but you could just use it as an internal resource. Here is how I would implement the PatientQueue class:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class PatientQueue {
    PriorityQueue pq;

    // default constructor
    public PatientQueue() {
        this.pq = new PriorityQueue<Patient>(1, new PatientComparator());
    }

    public void registerPatient(Patient p) {
        this.pq.add(p);
    } // end registerPatient method

    public Patient getNextPatient() {
        return (Patient) this.pq.poll();
    } // end getNextPatient method

} // end PatientQueue class
```

and in your EmergencyRoomSimulator class just change the field declaration to

`PatientQueue pq = new PatientQueue();`

Comment: Thank you - these 4 classes being created are specified in the assignment, so our hands are kind of stuck regarding the classes to use and the hierarchy.  But definitely appreciate the reply.

Comment: @SO-Darkater I edited the answer, maybe this could be more of help.

Comment: That works perfectly, except another requirement of the assignment is "Write a class called PatientComparator which implements the Comparator interface for comparing two Patients.  a) Patients with lower category numbers should be seen first. b) If the categories between 2 patients are equal, then the patient that arrived earlier should be seen first"  -- hence, I have to use that separate class.

Comment: But your way is definitely much more streamlined and easier to understand.  Again, greatly appreciate the tips.

Comment: @SO-Darkater You can just use the PatientComparator instead of the comparator I made in the PatientQueue class. Edited accordingly.

Comment: I was just coming here to post that I changed it to a new PatientComparator and it worked.  Thanks so much for the assistance.  It's starting to come together in my mind now.  I'll keep reading the API documentation - fascinating stuff!

Comment: Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `PatientQueue` does not use the `PatientComparator`. You should use the super class's constructor to register it.

And your `PatientQueue` does not add `Patient` objects to the queue. Add them in the `registerPatient` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  In your first comment, you're saying I should use the super class (PriorityQueue)'s constructor to create a new instance of a priority queue?  Similar to this: "PatientComparator pc;" as a data field?

Comment: And regarding the second statement: That's exactly where I'm stuck.  The queue itself gets created in the main method, and when I reference "pq" (the object created in main) it won't resolve.  Using "this.add(p);" causes a NullPointerException.

Comment: I mean you have to find a way to give the PriorityQueue the comparator. Since your PatientQueue extends PriorityQueue you should use the super constructor.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll do some more reading and figure out how pass the comparator to the PriorityQueue created in the main.